# How to operate with time/date values on Java?

Tags: java, date, time

I'm working on a Java program where the user, at some point, give us as an input two times (in format `String`). We can assume the times are from the same day. For example in the console:

```
Please introduce time 1:
16:00

Please introduce time 2:
10:00
```

My program will capture those two time values as a `String` and my idea was to parse it into an object of class `Date`.

How could I calculate which time goes first in the course of a day?

For the previous example, I would like to print the first time that takes place on the day.

How can I properly do the following?

```
if (date1 <= date2) System.out.println(date1);   //Suppose date1 and date2 are Date objects
else System.out.println(date2);
```

Comment: This is a very general question, you would be best advised to forget the Date (And Calendar) classes and instead read a [tutorial on the new java time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String firstDateString = "16:00";
String secondDateString = "10:00";

LocalTime firstLocalTime = LocalTime.parse(firstDateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
LocalTime secondLocalTime = LocalTime.parse(secondDateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));

if (firstLocalTime.isAfter(secondLocalTime)) {
  System.out.println(secondLocalTime);
} else {
  System.out.println(firstLocalTime);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. You don’t need the formatters. Just `LocalTime.parse(firstDateString)` works too.